# Why does svg filter fecomposite arithmetic on safari and ios return wrong colors?

Tags: ios, svg, filter, safari

fecomposite using arithmetic operation is defined to give:

```
result = k1*i1*i2 + k2*i1 + k3*i2 + k4

<feComposite in="edgesa" in2="gifimga" result="edgeedgea" operator="arithmetic" k1="1.0" k2="0.0" k3="0.0" k4="0.0" ></feComposite>
```

edgeedgea is a black and white checkerboard image.

fecomposite with these attributes should result in black where the checkerboard is black and should result in original pixel values from edgesa where the checkerboard is white.

works on chrome & firefox
wrong colors on safari on mac & iphone & chrome on iphone

sample codepen:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/leubeach/pen/zYrMeGz)

```
<svg height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
<filter id="Blue80s2" >
<feImage href="https://publish.responsiveads.com/ads/5e9d9ef50a33285b4a0000db/img/hertzc.png" result="gifimga"></feImage>
<feImage href="https://servedbyadbutler.com/getad.img/?libBID=930714" result="edgesa"></feImage>
<feComposite in="edgesa" in2="gifimga" result="edgeedgea" operator="arithmetic" k1="1.0" k2="0.0" k3="0.0" k4="0.0" ></feComposite>
<feMerge><feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode><feMergeNode in="edgeedgea" ></feMergeNode></feMerge>
</filter></defs></svg>
```

please advise
thank you
leu

Comment: Maybe the wrong colours are due to linearRGB colourspace not being supported properly on those platforms.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Do you have any reference about linearRGB not being supported properly on those platforms? Is there a way to prevent/undo gamma correction?